# how to dynamically modifying unitName in @PersistenceContext

Tags: jpa, ejb, persistence, cdi, entitymanager

I'm using JPA 2.1 and I have somthing like this

```
public class EntityManagerProducer {
    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="first_PU")
    private EntityManager em;
    ...
```

How can I dynamically modify the `unitName` in `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "somer_PU")` to use an other entity manager? Is this possible?

> VERY IMPORTANT UPDATE

I have a deployed application,the `persistence.xml` look like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="db1" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50"/>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
  <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:app/entitymanager/db1"/>
  <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:app/entitymanagerfactory/db1"/>
</properties>
```

At runtime, could modify the persistence.xml and add another persistence unit but I need a way to get the entitymanager that I need by passing the name of the persistence unit or something, and then using it for what I want. Then I could provide another name  of persistence unit and get a different entitymanager. Of course I would like that the transaction process still be **container-managed**.

Comment: Sorry, but still I see no purpose in changing persistence unit name at runtime. Can you explain? Does your application need to talk to multiple, different databases? And what do you mean by *At runtime, could modify the persistence.xml ...* ?

Comment: I mean, it could add more persistence units, when the application is deployed on the server. And yes I need my application can talk to multiple, different databases.

Comment: But wouldn't be enough for you to define dynamically just the DataSource? To be honest, you can in your java code connect to any database: jest open a connection and execute desired SQL statements (without using `EntityManager`).
BTW: is the amount of databases your application talk to a fixed number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Believe me, you don't want to modify the `unitName` inside existing `PersistenceContext`. I'm almost sure that all you want to achieve is to have a second `EntityManager` pointing to a different database, right?

Then a natural way to go is:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "first_PU")
    EntityManager firstEntityManager;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "somer_PU")
    EntityManager secondEntityManager;

    // ...
}
```

---

**Personal advices**

1. Please also notice that when using EJB, you don't have to create `Producer` methods for the EntityManager, as typing `@PersistenceContext(...)` is enough.
2. Also following is highly discouraged:

   ```
   @Produces
   @PersistenceContext(unitName="first_PU")
   private EntityManager em;
   ```

   because default scope is `@Dependent`. Much better would be `@RequestScoped` or `@TransactionScoped`.
3. Instead of hard-coded unit names you can use CDI and annotations qualifiers:

   ```
   @Inject
   private @FirstDB EntityManager firstEntityManager;

   @Inject
   private @SecondDB EntityManager secondEntityManager;
   ```

   But then you need to have:

   ```
   @Produces
   @RequestScoped // or other
   @FirstDB
   public EntityManager createEntityManagerA() {
       return firstEmf.createEntityManager();
   }

   @Produces
   @RequestScoped  // or other
   @SecondDB
   public EntityManager createEntityManagerB() {
       return secondEmf.createEntityManager();
   }
   ```

A lot of useful information about CDI and producing multiple EntityManagers you can find [here](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jpa.html).

Comment: Hello, G. Demecki, your answer and the link you gave me, was great help, they helped me clarify some doubts I had. But unfortunately my situation is a little more complicated because i dont know what persistence unit i would use at runtime,and i dont know how many could have, so i can hardcode those Entitymanagers. I update my question a bit, and if more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Do you need to close the EntityManagers created by this method?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  If you need a dynamic persistence unit name, you would need to avoid EE integration altogether and use the javax.persistence.Persistence class directly, but I would not recommend doing that.  As an alternative, you could inject EntityManager/Factory for all persistence units, and then select the correct one using a switch statement or similar.

Comment: you could suggest an example using the alternative you propose?